# shorthand for css class declarations

Tags: css

I am creating some css that is getting repetative:

```
.moduletable_homePosition001,
.moduletable_homePosition002,
etc to at least 012
```

Is there some short hand way that I can declare all these class names - perhaps with a variable like you'd do in php or js?

Comment: You might want to look at [less](http://lesscss.org). Or redesign your HTML structure.

Comment: Why don't you just add a common class to all of them

Comment: do you use sass? sass does this kind of automation

Comment: yes I could add a common class - but I was curious if there was a short hand as per below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not using variables but you can do this:

```
[class^="moduletable_homePosition"] {
    /* apply styles here */
}
```

The above uses "starts with selector"

Comment: thanks Amit - works well (once I spotted the deliberate typo!). Does this sort of selector have a name so I can look it up?

Comment: @maxelcat "starts with selector". BTW welcome and glad to have helped you ;)